# Django oAuth2 without saving the user into the database

Tags: django

I'm currently coding a website with Django and I successfully implemented an external oAuth2. (I'm not using any libraries) the problem is that the user is saved in the database. I would like to avoid it for hosting costs reasons.

In my current project, the oAuth2 is purely for verification purposes.

Is there a way in Django to log in a user in without saving him to the database? I would like the website to keep him logged in if the page is refreshed but logged out if the page is closed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered storing the user using django's session? You can save your user in the `request` like so `request.session["user"] = user`. However the `user` here must be in a dict format. Then to check if a user is logged in you can do something like `request.session["user"].is_authenticated` or whatever property you need.